# Adding taxonomy term to single CPT pages removes body classes from regular pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I wanted to add the taxonomy term for single CPT pages so I did that by using the code below:

```
//* Add CPT taxonomy terms to body class
function add_taxonomy_to_single( $classes ) {
  if ( is_single() ) {
    global $post;
    $my_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'skill' );
    if ( $my_terms && ! is_wp_error( $my_terms ) ) {
      foreach ($my_terms as $term) {
        $classes[] = $term->slug;
      }
    }
    return $classes;
  }
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_taxonomy_to_single' );
```

It worked fine for the intended single CPT pages as shown below. "selected-works" is the taxonomy term.

`<body data-rsssl="1" class="project-template-default single single-project postid-4829 logged-in woocommerce-js selected-works chrome">`

But, unfortunately, it also affected the regular pages (that weren't single). For the regular pages, it removed all of the classes from `body`.

```
<body data-rsssl="1" class="chrome">
```

How can I alter the code so it only affects the single CPT pages and no other pages?

Comment: Try moving the `return $classes;` out of the `if` statement.

Comment: @disinfor It worked, thank you.

Comment: Right on! I added it as an answer, as I think it's valuable for others who run into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer from my comment:

You need to move the `return $classes` out of the `if` statement:

```
//* Add CPT taxonomy terms to body class
function add_taxonomy_to_single( $classes ) {
  if ( is_single() ) {
    global $post;
    $my_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'skill' );
    if ( $my_terms && ! is_wp_error( $my_terms ) ) {
      foreach ($my_terms as $term) {
        $classes[] = $term->slug;
      }
    }
  }

return $classes;

}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_taxonomy_to_single' );
```

The reason is that the `body_class` filter hook gets run on page load, so when you are passing in `$classes` to your filter function, if the `if` statement isn't satisfied, unless the `return` is outside of the `if`, the `$classes` argument never gets returned to the original filter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_singular( 'your_cpt_name' );` rather than `is_single()` and also pass your `CPT Name` inside it like below.

```
//* Add CPT taxonomy terms to body class
function add_taxonomy_to_single( $classes ) {
  if ( is_singular('your_cpt_name') ) {
    global $post;
    $my_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'skill' );
    if ( $my_terms && ! is_wp_error( $my_terms ) ) {
      foreach ($my_terms as $term) {
        $classes[] = $term->slug;
      }
    }
    return $classes;
  }
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_taxonomy_to_single' );
```